# Toggle all buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button

I have a requirement to create an Email Preferences Page. So far I've got everything coded up and working correctly except for one detail. I'm using jQuery, jQuery-UI and another library (http://olance.github.io/jQuery-switchButton/) for the buttons which calls switchbutton() and converts the checkboxes to toggle like buttons which now look like this:

http://pages.norsecorp.com/rs/681-ONL-293/images/email-preference-center.html

The problem I'm having is trying to get the bottom button to control all the top buttons to toggle them all off or all on. I'm obviously still learning JavaScript so any help would be appreciated.

---

A snippet of my html:

```
 <div class="preferenceContainer">
    <div class="preferenceColumn"> 
     <div class="preferenceInfo" id="darkmatters"><h1><span class="heavy-weight">DARK</span>MATTERS<sup>&trade;</sup></h1><p>Copy on what readers will be getting in their inbox and what the basic idea of the communication is</p></div>
      <div class="toggle"> 
       <input type="checkbox" class="check-single" name='Newsletter__c' id='Newsletter__c' value="true" checked>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="preferenceColumn">
    <div class="preferenceInfo" id="flashreport"><h1>Flash Report</h1><p>Copy on what readers will be getting in their inbox and what the basic idea of the communication is</p></div>
     <div class="toggle"> 
      <input type="checkbox" class="check-single" name='Flash_Report__c' id='Flash_Report__c' value="true" checked>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="preferenceColumn" >
     <div class="preferenceInfo" id="threatintel"><h1>THREAT INTEL</h1><p>Copy on what readers will be getting in their inbox and what the basic idea of the communication is</p></div>
      <div class="toggle">
       <input type="checkbox" class="check-single" name='Threat_Intel__c' id='Threat_Intel__c' value="true" checked>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="form-break"/>
    <div class="preferenceAll">  <div class="toggle" id="toggle-all">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check-all" id="check-all"/>
    </div> <h2>Please Remove Me From All Communications</h2></div>
    </div>
```

---

The function I'm calling to convert my input checkboxes into toggle switches:

```
$(function() {
    $(".toggle input").switchButton({
      show_labels: false,
      width: 100,
      height: 40,
      button_width: 40,
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your JQuery as follows:

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zwdv5dLz/13/)

```
function toggleSwitches(show) {
  $(function() {
      $(".toggle input").switchButton({
        show_labels: false,
        width: 100,
        height: 40,
        button_width: 40,
        checked: show,
      });
    });
  }
  toggleSwitches(true); //Called when page first loads

  $('#toggle-all').change(function() {
    //Check if the "checked" class has been applied to the appropriate element. 
    //This will will be used to set the state of the inputs via the toggleSwitches function.
    var checked = $('#toggle-all .switch-button-background').hasClass('checked');

    toggleSwitches(!checked); //Use the inverse value to change the state
  })
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. Just curious about the "checked: show" attribute. Not sure I understand why that is needed?

Comment: That checked attribute sets the state of the check box. `show` is a boolean value and is set according to the current class that has been applied to the "toggle-all" check box. When the "toggle-all" check box has a class of checked, when it is next clicked, all of the check boxes need to be unchecked, thus why the `!check` value is used i.e. the opposite value.

Answer (score 0):

See code comments for explanation of what I am doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                //setup on change event listener on element id #check-all
                $("#check-all").on("change", function () {
                    //determine if #check-all is checked and store true/false in a variable
                    var checkAll = this.checked;
                    //loop through all check boxes with class .check-single
                    $(".check-single").each(function (index) {
                        //assign checkAll variable as state
                        //normal checkbox
                        //this.checked = checkAll;
                        //using switchbutton API
                        $(this).switchButton({ checked: checkAll });

                    });
                });

                $(".toggle input").switchButton({
                    show_labels: false,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 40,
                    button_width: 40,
                });
            })

        </script>
```